# Changing a property controller based on other controller's property value in wpf

Tags: wpf, data-binding, devexpress, wpf-controls

Consider in my wpf application, I have a checkbox and 2 textedits, as below:

```
<CheckBox x:Uid="Checkbox_1" FlowDirection="RightToLeft" IsChecked="{Binding TickCheckBox, Mode=TwoWay}" Style="{StaticResource StandardCheckBoxStyle}">My Checkbox</CheckBox>

<dxe:TextEdit x:Uid="dxe:TextEdit_1" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Width="100" Style="{StaticResource FleetScheduledHoursStyle}" EditValue="{Binding RealValue, Mode=OneWay}" EditMode="InplaceInactive" ToolTipService.ShowDuration="20000" />

<dxe:TextEdit x:Uid="dxe:TextEdit_2" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Width="100" Style="{StaticResource FleetScheduledHoursStyle}" EditValue="{Binding RealValue, Mode=OneWay}" EditMode="InplaceInactive" ToolTipService.ShowDuration="20000" />
```

The TickCheckBox is bound to a property in my viewmodel as below:

```
private bool tickCheckBox;
public bool TickCheckBox
{
    get
    {
        return this.tickCheckBox;
    }
    set
    {
        if (this.TickCheckBox.Equals(value))
        {
               return;
        }
        this.tiketCheckBox = value;
        this.NotifyPropertyChange(() => this.TickCheckBox);
    }
}
```

How do I change the property "EditMode" of one of the textedit (say Text_Edit1) to "InplaceActive" when I ticked the checkbox?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: question: your viewmodel is a [POCOViewModel](https://docs.devexpress.com/WPF/17352/mvvm-framework/viewmodels/poco-viewmodels) ?

Comment: Yes it is @Marlonchosky

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an `IValueConverter`:

**BoolToEditModeConverte.cs**

```
public class BoolToEditModeConverter : IValueConverter
{
  public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
  {
    if (!(value is bool isChecked))
    {
      throw new ArgumentException("Converter value must be of type 'bool'");
    }
    return isChecked 
      ? EditMode.InplaceInactive
      : EditMode.None;
  }

  public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
  {
    throw new NotSupportedException();
  }
}
```

**Usage**

```
<Window>
  <Window.Resources>
    <BoolToEditModeConverte x:Key="BoolToEditModeConverte" />
  </Window.Resources>

  <CheckBox x:Name="MyCheckbox" />

  <TextEdit EditMode="{Binding ElementName=MyCheckBox, 
                               Path=IsChecked, 
                               Converter={StaticResource BoolToEditModeConverte}}" />
</Window>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using POCOViewModel, you just define a property for the TextEdit.EditMode and binding in the xaml, and define a method for the TickCheckBox changed event in the poco view model, like this:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window {
    public MainWindow() {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.DataContext = Vm.Create();
    }
}

[POCOViewModel]
public class Vm {
    public virtual bool TickCheckBox { get; set; } = false;
    public virtual EditMode EditMode { get; set; } = EditMode.InplaceInactive;

    public static Vm Create() => ViewModelSource.Create(() => new Vm());

    protected void OnTickCheckBoxChanged() {
        if (this.TickCheckBox) {
            // or this.EditMode = EditMode.InplaceActive;
            this.EditMode = EditMode.Standalone;
        } else {
            this.EditMode = EditMode.InplaceInactive;
        }
    }
}
```

and the xaml:

```
<StackPanel>
    <CheckBox x:Uid="Checkbox_1" FlowDirection="RightToLeft" IsChecked="{Binding TickCheckBox, Mode=TwoWay}">
        My Checkbox
    </CheckBox>

    <dxe:TextEdit
        x:Uid="dxe:TextEdit_1"
        EditMode="{Binding EditMode}"
        EditValue="{Binding RealValue, Mode=OneWay}"
        ToolTipService.ShowDuration="20000" />
    <dxe:TextEdit
        x:Uid="dxe:TextEdit_2"
        EditMode="Standalone"
        EditValue="{Binding RealValue, Mode=OneWay}"
        ToolTipService.ShowDuration="20000" />
</StackPanel>
```

Comment: Your solution would work. But the reason why I chose not to suggest your solution and recommended to use a value converter instead is that it is generally not a good idea to have view properties in your view model. The edit mode relates to UI logic only and has no meaning for the application logic. Otherwise this property would be already present. The point is that the enumeration type only has meaning to the view. Furthermore the enumeration seems to be part of a 3rd party library.

Comment: If you decide to choose another control or library you will be forced to modify the view model (although this property has only a meaning to the view). I just came across your answer and thought you might be interested in consequences of design choices.

Comment: Exactly @BionicCode, the answer is DevExpress dependant, not a generic solution. Nevertheless, since the author of the question is using that library, I choose to write an answer by the capabilities of the library. If the software project that the problem is in, is in a mature phase, in my experienced, it's not a good choice to change the frameworks o libraries that depends. But if the project is in early phases (like testing libraries or frameworks), sure is a good choice give a generic solution.

Comment: Your solution is not generic as the view bleeds into the view model by adding a dependency to a view related library to the view model. It doesn't matter if this is a prototype or a product version. The nature of applications especially of the view is to change frequently. It's best to separate the view model from the view to enhance maintainability. Many times the view is  developed by a different team than the team that develops the view model and model. Also the view models most of the time reside in a separate assembly, which want to avoid to rebuild because of changes in the view.

Comment: Generic means, you can use your view model independently from libraries used by the view. Libraries used by view, should only be referenced by the view. Logic that is only relevant for the view should be implemented in the view.

Comment: You don't understand me. By generic, I mean a solution for the wpf framework and no for a library based on this framework. Use a IValueConverter is a generic solution for the WPF framework since the question is in the context of this kind of application. On other hand, it's valid use a property of a view inside a view model if you can test it.